# Exception thrown with models on Master Page View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple view in which I am trying to access the Model properties. None of the model properties are available at this time (this is the problem).

If I use a `<%= Model.blah %>` then you can see that the model properties are available.

In the last photo you will now see that I can access the Model properties that I was trying to access in the first photo.

An error will be thrown if viewing this page if you don't first do <%= with the model.

```
CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'User' and no extension method 'User' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view inherits `System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<AuthModel>` which of course is wrong as it is an `aspx` page. Make it inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AuthModel>` and it should work:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Base.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AuthModel>" 
%>
```